# Как избавиться от полного указания пути до файла

Tags: c++

В проекте создал папку "levels" и туда положил файл с картой, и если прописывать полный путь, то все работает.

```
ifstream level;
level.open("/users/Stolz/git/Roguelike/levels/level" + to_string(aLevelNumber) + ".map");
```

Но если указать путь как `"levels/level" + to_string(aLevelNumber) + ".map"` то он уже не видит файл, как можно это исправить?

Comment: (1) А какой у вас текущий каталог? (2) А какой у вас будет текущий каталог, если юзер запустит вашу программу из корневого каталога?

Comment: Подозреваю, что программа запускается не из каталога проекта, а из какого-нибудь подкаталога типа `./Release`, `./Debug` etc

Comment: @VladD текущий каталог Roguelike, в нем лежат все исполняемые файлы

Comment: @NicholasGoncharov, надо смотреть что лежит в `argv[0]` (и что скажет `getcwd()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько способов задать "точку отсчета", т.е. оглавление, зная которое мы можем вычислять все нужные нам пути к файлам конфигурации и т.п.

Это может быть переменная окружения, домашний каталог пользователя, запустившего программу и каталог в котором находится исполняемый код.

Система при запуске первым аргументом передает в программу ее имя, как его ввел пользователь в оболочке (или то, что указал программист, вызвавшей ее через [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl)).

Если имя запускаемой программы не содержит абсолютного или относительного (относительно текущего (откуда ее имя набирают) каталога) пути, то система ищет каталог с кодом программы в переменной окружения (environment) `PATH`, где через символ `:` перечислены каталоги.

Воспользовавшись этими знаниями, легко можно написать пару функций, которые получив имя из параметра командной строки, возвращают каталог в котором лежит запущенная программа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>


char *
srcpath (const char *pgm)
{
  char *path = getenv("PATH"),
    dir[PATH_MAX], *p;

  if (path)
    for (p = path; *p; *p ? p++ : p) {
      char *t = dir, *e = dir + PATH_MAX - 1;

      while (*p && *p != ':' && t < e)
        *t++ = *p++;
      if (snprintf(t, e - t, "/%s", pgm) < e - t &&
          access(dir, R_OK | X_OK) == 0)
        return strndup(dir, t - dir);
    }

  return 0;
}

char *
srcdir (const char *av0)
{
  const char *pgm = strrchr(av0, '/');

  return pgm ? strndup(av0, pgm - av0) : srcpath(av0);
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *dir;

  for (; *av; av++) {
    printf("%s : %s\n", av[0], dir = srcdir(av[0]));
    free(dir);
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

По крайней мере в Linux-е (начиная с 2.2) в каталоге [/proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) для каждого процесса есть файл (на самом деле символьный линк) `/proc/[pid]/exe`, содержащий полный путь к исполняемому файлу.

Напишем аналогичную функцию, которая извлекает каталог из `/proc`:

```
char *
linux_srcdir ()
{
  char buf[PATH_MAX];
  int n = readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, PATH_MAX);

  return n > 0 ? buf[n] = 0, strndup(buf, strrchr(buf, '/') - buf) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый дубовый вариант - берете из `argv[0]` (передается в `main`) путь к вашему исполняемому файлу, обрезаете в нем все с конца до левого слеша, потом вклеиваете туда путь к нужному подкаталогу.

Способов раздобыть путь к выполняемому файлу - [огромное количество](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable).

[Хороший способ найти слеш](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071694/5533854):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) 
{
    assert(argc>0);

    static constexpr char levels_dir[]="levels";
    static constexpr char slashes[]="/\\";

    const string bin_path(argv[0]);

    const auto slash_position = bin_path.find_last_of(slashes);

    assert(slash_position!=string::npos);

    const auto levels_path    = bin_path.substr(0,slash_position+1) 
                              + levels_dir
                              + bin_path[slash_position];

    cout << "Bin path: "     << bin_path    << endl 
         << "Levels_path: "  << levels_path << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вариант кроссплатформенный - работает и с прямым и с обратным слешем.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/o9Hnsn)

Comment: argv[0] не обязательно содержит рабочую директорию

Comment: @VladimirGamalian рабочая директория нам даром не нужна, нам нужна та, в которой бинарник лежит. Так как очевидно, что уровни игрушки должны лежать рядом с бинарником.

Comment: argv[0] не обязательно показывает директорию с бинарником

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian если это какой-то совсем чокнутый UNIX, там может содержаться мусор, согласен.

Comment: Вызов через `execve` (например из прелоадера/апдейтера игры) позволит любой argv[0] указать. Соответственно `find_last_of` может вернуть `npos`, который дальше как индекс для `bin_path` используется, что сами понимаете к чему ведет.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian я написал в начале - ЭТО ДУБОВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ. Надежный  и переносимый вариант потребует тащить сюда либо boost, Qt, далее везде, либо писать велосипедный аналог.

Comment: У вас же стоит `assert` на кол-во аргументов, почему бы не поставить и на `slash_position != string::npos` (даже если это дубовый вариант).

Comment: `Так как очевидно, что уровни игрушки должны лежать рядом с бинарником. ` не очевидно, т.к. на Linux обычно не практикуется такое.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian сторонний софт на UNIX обычно валит все в свою папку в /opt

Comment: А если программа лежит в `PATH`?

Comment: @gbg, *обычно* уже давно кладут кто куда хочет. Например, в `/usr/share`, в `~/.programname`, и т.д. А то и во всем места сразу.